# How to access properties in a nested hashtable without explicitly stating the property names?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-7.2

Let's say I have a 2-level nested hashtable like this:

```
$programs = @{


    program1 = @{
        DisplayName = "DisplayName1"
        Program = "C:\program1.exe"

    }

    program2 = @{
        DisplayName = "DisplayName2"
        Program = "C:\program2.exe"

    }

    }
```

now, without explicitly mentioning each of the property names like this:

```
$programs.program1['program']
```

I want to iterate over the hashtable like this:

```
foreach ($Name in $programs) {


$r = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $programs.Keys['DisplayName'] 2> $null; 
if (-NOT $r) { 
                         
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $programs.Keys['DisplayName']  -Program $program.Keys['Program']
         
}

}
```

but I keep getting errors like:

```
 Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DisplayName'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
InvalidOperation: untitled:Untitled-2:29:13
```

what am I doing wrong?

what is the right way to access nested hashtable properties like this without explicitly mentioning their names? I want to know the synatx of it so that if I ever have a 3 or 4 level nested hashtables I can access them without specifying their exact names.

even if we ignore the foreach loop, how to only list all the "DisplayName" properties? what if the "DisplayName" properties were in a 4-level nested hashtable and we wanted to list them in the PowerShell console without specifying the exact names of the items that came before it?

Comment: You're looking for `$programs.Values.DisplayName` and `$program.Values.Program`

Comment: Iterating over a hashtable works slightly different from other containers: `foreach( $prog in $programs.GetEnumerator() ) { Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $prog.Value.DisplayName }`

Comment: Thank you, even though I enclosed the programs and display names in double quotes to be string, I still get this error `Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'DisplayName'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.`

Comment: I would do it as a csv then import-csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) and [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42), here is the syntax to access properties of deeply nested hashtables.

```
$programs.Values.Values.Values and so on.
```

I found it work perfectly.

also, after [reading foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.3) and as mentioned in the comments, I found that my code above was incorrect and the correct way is this:

```
foreach ($Name in $programs.values.GetEnumerator()) {


$r = Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $Name.DisplayName 2> $null; 
if (-NOT $r) { 
                         
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $Name.DisplayName -Program $Name.Program
         
}

}
```

in a foreach loop, we have to use the variable we create in the parenthesis. my mistake was that I was using the collection itself again.